# Alamofire - Boolean as parameter is always 0

Tags: post, swift2, boolean, alamofire

I am using Alamofire for API Calls , Having Boolean value in a parameter , But after doing a POST Request Server end always get 0 that is false.

**My Parameter Object :-**

```
        let para : [String: AnyObject] = [
            "UserId"      : UserDefault.getUserId(),
            "IsOnline"    : 1,
            "LocationLat" : driverCurrentLat,
            "LocationLong": driverCurrentLong,
            "IpAddress"   : "\(ipAddr)"
        ]
```

// URL
        let urlPath = BASE_SERVER.stringByAppendingString(serviceName)

**//Alamofire POST Req.**

```
        var defaultHeaders =    Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance.session.configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders ?? [:]
        defaultHeaders["Authorization"] = "Bearer \(UserDefault.getUserToken())"
        let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
        configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = defaultHeaders
        //configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 10
        let manager = Alamofire.Manager(configuration: configuration)
        manager.request(.POST, urlPath, parameters: parameters as? [String : AnyObject])
            .responseJSON { response in

                manager.session.invalidateAndCancel()
                if let JSON = response.result.value
                {
                    print("JSON: \(JSON)")
                    withCompletionHandler(success:true, responseDictionary:JSON,error:nil)

                }else{
                    withCompletionHandler(success:false, responseDictionary:nil ,error:response.result.error)

                }
```

Comment: Fixed - Answer may be not justified - But i had to send true as a string "true" even though on server end it is a Boolean. 

Thanks